XIM doesn't work: "No IM module matching GTK_IM_MODULE=xim found"
I'm trying to get exwm-xim from Emacs EXWM work. I have done everything I needed to do, including setting the environment variables (GTK_IM_MODULES=xim and XMODIFIERS=@im=exwm-xim to be precise) and calling (exwm-xim-enable). But it doesn't work. I suddenly noticed today that all the GTK programs output something like the following:
(dino:14531): Gtk-WARNING **: 02:52:19.528: No IM module matching GTK_IM_MODULE=xim found

How can I fix this? I'm on GNU Guix System, with the whole system updated just 2 days ago.
I guess I'm missing some package I need to install, but I can't find out which one.
